# Feller's Introduction to probability - Configuration of 7 balls in 7 cells

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

I am not sure, if my understanding of the below problem is correct. Any inputs/insight would be extremely helpful.

On page 38, Feller writes :

> Configuration of $r=7$ balls in $n=7$ cells.
>
> For the sake of definiteness, let us consider the distributions with occupancy numbers $2,2,1,1,1,0,0$ appearing in an arbitrary order. These seven occupancy numbers induce a partition of seven cells into three sub-populations (categories) consisting respectively, of the two doubly occupied, the three simply occupied and the two empty cells. Such a partition into three groups can be effected in $7!/(2!3!2!)$ ways.
>
> To each particular assignment of our occupancy numbers to the seven cells, there correspond $7!/(2!2!1!1!0!0!)$ different distributions of the $r=7$ balls into the seven cells.
>
> Accordingly, the total number of distributions such that occupancy numbers co-incide with $2,2,1,1,1,0,0$ in some order is:
>
> $$\frac{7!}{2!3!2!}\times\frac{7!}{2!2!1!1!0!0!}$$

First term.

I understand that the first term on the left, are the possible permutations of two doubly-occupied, three singly occupied and two empty-cells, that is, orderings of the occupancy numbers. For example, $\{2,2,1,1,1,0,0\},\{2,1,2,1,1,0,0\},\ldots$. We are just partitioning $n=7$ cells into $3$ sub-populations.

Second term.

Suppose we have, $7$ balls labelled $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$. We are to classify them into groups of size $2,2,1,1,0,0$. This gives $7!/(2!2!1!1!1!0!0!)$ possible groupings.

$\implies$ the possible distributions with occupancy numbers $2,2,1,1,0,0$ in an arbitrary order is:

$$\frac{7!}{2!3!2!}\times\frac{7!}{2!2!1!1!1!0!0!}$$

Comment: That's right. What is the question?

Comment: @leonbloy, how are we making sure, the balls in pairs don't go to a cell with occupancy number $1$. The explanation above hasn't entirely sunk in. :)

Answer (score 3):

It might be more helpful to view the second term as
$$
 \binom{7}{2} \binom{5}{2} \binom{3}{1} \binom{2}{1} \binom{1}{1},
$$
as there are $\binom{7}{2}$ ways to select 2 balls to place in the first group of size 2, $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to select 2 of the remaining balls to place in the second group of size 2, etc.